# Elasticsearch : php variable into query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal

I have a query which works. But i want to replace a part with a php variable, so the problem it's an array is generated and the query doesn't works.

This query works :

```
...[query] => Array
            (
                [filtered] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => Array
                            (
                                [multi_match] => Array
                                    (
                                        [query] => Baden-Powell
                                        [fields] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => title
                                                [1] => field_auteur
                                                [2] => body:value
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        ...
```

The field can be empty so i want to replace this part [query] [multi_match], by a variable like this :

```
'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            $querytitle,
            ...
```

And $querytitle =

```
$querytitle= "'query' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => $SearchSimple,
                            'fields' => ['title', 'field_auteur', 'body:value']
                            ]
                        ],
                    ";
or $querytitle="";
```

The generated code is :

```
[query] => Array
            (
                [filtered] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 'query' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => Baden-Powell,
                            'fields' => ['title', 'field_auteur', 'body:value']
                            ]
                        ],
```

The problem is the "Array [0]" before 'query'.
How I can integrate my variable $querytitle, to have a request which works ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why does the `$querytitle` variable contain a string instead of simply containing an associative array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the `$querytitle` variable contains a string instead of simply containing an associative array.

Try like this instead:

```
$querytitle = Array('query' => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'query' => $SearchSimple,
                        'fields' => ['title', 'field_auteur', 'body:value']
                        ]
                    ]
             );
```

Then you need to write your new query like this (i.e. without the square bracket after `filtered`):

```
'query' => [
    'filtered' => $querytitle,
        ...
```

Comment: Yes i have already tried with "Array()". but it's same :                     [filtered] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [query] => ...

Comment: That's because you need to write your new query like this without the square bracket after `filtered`, see my updated answer

Comment: Yes ! But is missing the square bracket at the end of query so it's not works.

Comment: Of course if your remove the opening bracket, you need to remove the closing one.

Comment: Oh i am really sorry for my tired and little relevant answer! My request is complex but I succeeded. Thanks to your advice. Thank you again a lot.